# jquery mobile style doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, navbar

Why is my page is looking like this? I am not able to find the problem

[image]

Is that all right?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

HTMl:

```
<div data-role="header" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h1>I'm a header</h1>
        <a href="#" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
```

Comment: you are loading both the minimized and development versions of the jQM css and js files. Only load one or the other (.min is probably what you want).

Comment: Okay thanks. but i have still the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using any *external* widget, you need to add `data-theme="a"` or `"b"`.

The normal behavior, widgets inherit theme from parent div. however, since parent of external widget is *body* and *body* doesn't receive any theme, hence External widgets should be themed.

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
</div>
```

Comment: i add the data theme and role but still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Erdem in `head` place the following link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">`, `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>` and last `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>`.

Comment: Still the same problem. and i get no errors in my console?!

Comment: @Erdem the button "scan" is styled in your image. Make sure you have elements inside `div data-role=page` and add `data-theme=a`.

Comment: Thanks omar, i tried a bit and it works now :) Very helpfull from you

Answer (score 0):

Check if your javascript files and css files are loaded correctly and if your paths are ok.
And you might have forgotten an extra div :

```
<div data-role="page">
</div>
```

which is the main div that contains all your html.
If these pointers don't work let me know.

Comment: Yeah the files are correctly loaded and i have an extra div with data-role as page.. but still doesn't work